# Installing VirtualBox in Ubuntu 20.04 - Errors were encountered while processing various packages

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, dpkg

```
 $ sudo apt install virtualbox virtualbox-ext-pack 
 Reading package lists... Done  
 Building dependency tree        
 Reading state information... Done 
 The following additional packages will be installed: 
   libgsoap-2.8.91 libqt5opengl5 libvncserver1 virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt 
 Suggested packages: 
   vde2 virtualbox-guest-additions-iso 
 The following NEW packages will be installed: 
   libgsoap-2.8.91 libqt5opengl5 libvncserver1 virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-ext-pack 
   virtualbox-qt 
 0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
 Need to get 0 B/44.3 MB of archives. 
 After this operation, 180 MB of additional disk space will be used. 
 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y 
 Preconfiguring packages ... 
 Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-dkms. 
(Reading database ... 314591 files and directories currently installed.) 
 Preparing to unpack .../0-virtualbox-dkms_6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1_amd64.deb ... 
 Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) ... 
 Selecting previously unselected package libgsoap-2.8.91:amd64. 
 Preparing to unpack .../1-libgsoap-2.8.91_2.8.91-2_amd64.deb ... 
 Unpacking libgsoap-2.8.91:amd64 (2.8.91-2) ... 
 Selecting previously unselected package libvncserver1:amd64. 
 Preparing to unpack .../2-libvncserver1_0.9.12+dfsg-9ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb ... 
 Unpacking libvncserver1:amd64 (0.9.12+dfsg-9ubuntu0.3) ... 
 Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox. 
 Preparing to unpack .../3-virtualbox_6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1_amd64.deb ... 
 Unpacking virtualbox (6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) ... 
 Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-ext-pack. 
 Preparing to unpack .../4-virtualbox-ext-pack_6.1.10-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1_all.deb ... 
 License has already been accepted. 
 Unpacking virtualbox-ext-pack (6.1.10-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) ... 
 Selecting previously unselected package libqt5opengl5:amd64. 
 Preparing to unpack .../5-libqt5opengl5_5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ... 
 Unpacking libqt5opengl5:amd64 (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ... 
 Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-qt. 
 Preparing to unpack .../6-virtualbox-qt_6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1_amd64.deb ... 
 Unpacking virtualbox-qt (6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) ... 
 Setting up libvncserver1:amd64 (0.9.12+dfsg-9ubuntu0.3) ... 
 Setting up libqt5opengl5:amd64 (5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1) ... 
 Setting up libgsoap-2.8.91:amd64 (2.8.91-2) ... 
 Setting up virtualbox-dkms (6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) ... 
 Loading new virtualbox-6.1.10 DKMS files... 
 Building for 5.4.0-58-generic 5.8.1-050801-generic 
 Building initial module for 5.4.0-58-generic 
 Secure Boot not enabled on this system. 
 Done. 
  
 vboxdrv.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/updates/dkms/ 
  
 vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/updates/dkms/ 
  
 vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/updates/dkms/ 
  
 depmod......... 
  
 DKMS: install completed. 
 Building initial module for 5.8.1-050801-generic 
 ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.8.1-050801-generic is not supported 
 Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.1-050801-generic (x86_64) 
 Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information. 
 dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-dkms (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status
 10 
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox:
 virtualbox depends on virtualbox-dkms (>= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-source (>=
 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1) | virtualbox-modules; however:
  Package virtualbox-dkms is not configured yet.
  Package virtualbox-source is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-modules is not installed.
  Package virtualbox-dkms which provides virtualbox-modules is not configured yet. 
  
 dpkg: error processing package virtualbox (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-ext-pack:
 virtualbox-ext-pack depends on virtualbox (>= 6.1.10-dfsg-0~) | virtualbox-6.1; however:
  Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
  Package virtualbox-6.1 is not installed.
 virtualbox-ext-pack depends on virtualbox (<< 6.1.10-dfsg-z) | virtualbox-6.1; however:
  Package virtualbox is not configured yet.
  Package virtualbox-6.1 is not installed. 
  
 dpkNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure. 
 No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure. 
 No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already 
 g: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--configure): 
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-qt: 
 virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1); however: 
   Package virtualbox is not configured yet. 

 dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-qt (--configure): 
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured 
 Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ... 
 Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ... 
 Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ... 
 Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ... 
 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ... 
 Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.3) ... 
 Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ... 
 Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ... 
 Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.15-1) ... 
 Errors were encountered while processing: 
  virtualbox-dkms 
  virtualbox 
  virtualbox-ext-pack 
  virtualbox-qt 
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I know since:

`Secure Boot not enabled on this system.` Don't you think is it saying something here?

By the way, you must have enabled Virtual Machine in your boot configuration IF your machine does support it.

> Because it could simply be that your machine doesn't support it.

Then:

`ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.8.1-050801-generic is not supported`

Don't underestimate the @Pilot6 answer since it will cure many headaches in the future!

Ubuntu as Linux kernel had lots of changes recently and many applications stop working as expected which has led to tweaks, adaptations, complications, and angry users like me.

You'll need to install :

```
Package virtualbox-source is not installed.
Package virtualbox-modules is not installed.
```

thus,

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox:
```

It seems like:

- 1st your kernel doesn't support it
- 2nd you'll need to install missing modules
- 3rd to configure them if the automatic installation doesn't it

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error, except I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with the 5.19 kernel.

What solved it for me was looking into
`/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log` file that the error message suggested to check out.

The file said my currently used gcc version was 11.2.0 but my kernel was built with gcc 12.2.0, or something like that. So I downloaded gcc 12:
`sudo apt-get install gcc-12`

After that, I removed the the `/usr/bin/gcc` symbolic link and created a new one that points to gcc-12, instead of gcc-11 (in my case): `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-12 /usr/bin/gcc`

Purge virtualbox and reinstall

`sudo apt-get purge virtualbox`

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox`

And no errors! Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

You are using an unsupported mainline kernel `5.8.1-050801-generic`.

The virtualbox package from Ubuntu repositories is incompatible with it as you can see the kernel module doesn't build:

```
DKMS: install completed. 
 Building initial module for 5.8.1-050801-generic 
 ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.8.1-050801-generic is not supported 
 Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.1-050801-generic (x86_64) 
 Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information.
```

And it seems Oracle didn't release VB that supports the `5.8` kernel yet. I don't see a release for Ubuntu 20.10 at virtualbox.org.

So switch to an Ubuntu kernel and all should work.